Solve in the set of natural numbers the equation: $x^3+y^3=x^2yz$
the problem
Solve in the set of natural numbers the equation:
$x^3+y^3=x^2yz$
my idea
So first thing that came into my mind was that $x^3+y^3=(x+y)(x^2-xy+y^2)$ so we have to solve $(x+y)(x^2-xy+y^2)=x^2yz$
From here I thought of working with modular arithmetic but I didn't know how to start. Maybe also using the quadric formula may work.
Hope one of you can help me! Thank you!

Let $g = \gcd(x,y)$, then $x=ag$ and $y=bg$ for some relatively prime natural $a,b$. So we have $$g^3(a^3+b^3)= g^3a^2bz \implies a^2\mid b^3\implies a=1$$
So we have now $$b^3+1= bz \implies b\mid 1\implies b=1$$
so $z=2$. Thus exactly each triple $(g,g,2)$ is a solution, where $g$ is arbitrary natural.

Thank you so much for your answer. May I ask why $a^2|b^3$ means that a=1. I know that $(a,b)=1$ but how does this help? Thanks!

If there a prime $p$ which divides $a$ then also $p\mid b^3$ since $a^2\mid b^3$. So $p\mid b$ but this is impossible. So there is no prime which divides $a$.

But why is it impossible? This doesn't mean that $a,b$ have a common divisor.

Sorry, I'don't understand what are you saying.

Can you tell me if im right? Im saying that we get to the fact that $p|b^3$ and because p is prime => $p|b$ we do the same thing with $p|a$ but because $(a,b)=1$ we get that a=1
